# let $P \subseteq T$ ,then which of the following option are correct?

Tags: general-topology

Given  $T $ be  a topological  space and let $K_1 , K_2$ be two dense  subsets  of $T.$ let $P \subseteq T$ ,then

which  of the  following option are correct ?

$1.$ $ P \cap K_1 $ is dense in $P$

$2.$ $P \cap K_1$ is  dense in  $P$  if $P$ is  open

$3.$$P \cap K_1 \cap K_2$ is dense in $P$ if  $P$ is  open

$4.$ $P \cap K_1 \cap K_2$  is dense  in $P$ if  $P, K_1,K_2 $ are  all open

My attempt  :  i thinks  option $1$ is the  only correct option

take  $T = \mathbb{R}$ and $K_1 = \mathbb{Q} , K_2 = \mathbb{Q^c}$

Is  its  true ?

any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: My guess is that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are $K_1$ and $K_2$. Am I right?

Comment: yes@JoséCarlosSantos  i  edits its

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're wrong. You don't give a $P$ in your example, BTW.

Taking the rationals and irrationals as $K_1$ and $K_2$ invalidates 1: take $P$ the irrationals too, then $P \cap K_1$ is empty, not dense.

Variations of the rationals/irrationals will be counterexamples to 1 and 3. What remains is 2 and 4, which can be proved rather easily.

Comment: i edits  my question.... which  option is correct ?

Comment: @jasmine see my edits.

Comment: thanks u  @Henno sir

Comment: @Henno: how second one is false?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR after the edits it’s true again. The OP has changed the question a few times so I got confused.